# Object thatHolds Arrays JQuery

Tags: javascript

How can I make an Object that holds arrays as element. I tried that:

```
   var dMap = new Object();
   ...
   if (dMap[d.name] === undefined) {
           dMap[d.name] = p.name;
        } else {
           dMap[d.name].push(p.name);// It gives error here
    }
   ...
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially add an array, by adding square brackets around your variable:

```
...
if (typeof dMap[d.name] == "undefined") {
        dMap[d.name] = [p.name]; //<-- [ and ] added!
     } else {
        dMap[d.name].push(p.name);
 }
```

Also, to test whether a variable/property is defined or not, use `typeof variable == "undefined"`, because `undefined` can be overwritten by anything, causing the comparison to break:

```
undefined = "broken";
var obj = {};
obj.notdeclared == undefined; //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `dMap[d.name] = p.name;` to `dMap[d.name] = [p.name];` and it should work.

The reason it doesn't work now is that you're setting `dMap[d.name]` to (I assume) a string, and then trying to push another element onto it -- which doesn't make sense. Push is an array operation, so what you really want to do is to set it to the array containing `p.name`, to which you can then append additional elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to write:

```
if (dMap[d.name] === undefined) {
    dMap[d.name] = [p.name]; // IMPORTANT CHANGE HERE
} else {
    dMap[d.name].push(p.name);
}
```

This way (with the bracket notation) you are creating an array as you probably intend to do.